# How to get exactly the id of the last inserted record in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a web application, which can be used by multiple users simultaneously. They can add data at the same time.

I have a table named doctor_main as follows

[Screenshot of DB http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/7033/testxqz.png](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/7033/testxqz.png)

Once a record about a doctor is added, I want the id of the inserted record(which is an auto increment field) to be returned.

I know i can use methods like LAST_INSERT_ID() and mysql_insert_id. But i don't know how it behaves.

I need the exact id of the record which is inserted by that particular user.

Sometimes, if two users are trying to insert a record, the id which is returned shouldn't get exchanged.

To achieve this what kind of mysql function should i use ?

Comment: Why not take it on trust.... it works, better minds than yours have worked on this for years. The ID That is returned is the id of the last insert by that user's thread, not by any other user's thread

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() is on a per MySQL connection basis, for an id that has been autogenerated by an AUTO_INCREMENT column. So as long as you call LAST_INSERT_ID() on the same connection, after you did your INSERT, there's no concurrency problem.

Comment: @MarkBaker Yeap, I hope better minds than me worked on this for years, that is why i asked the better minds here to make sure. There is no crime in having doubts and getting clarified than just following. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a whole page in the manual dedicated to this subject:

- [How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Here's a quote from that page that should help answer your question:

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client.

Comment: @All I found mysql_insert_id is the best choice to achieve my task :) thanks alot for responding

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_insert_id()` returns exactly the id of the last inserted record, so if you just `echo mysql_insert_id()` you'll get the id of the very last inserted row.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php), the `mysql_insert_id` will return to you the exact id of the insert that you done before.

Answer (score 2):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` and `mysql_insert_id` works fine. Each client will receive the last inserted `ID` for the last statement that client executed.

Answer (score 2):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` operates per-connection; multiple users will use multiple connections, so there will never be an exchange of IDs between users.

Answer (score -1):

If you are suspicious on the mechanism of `last_insert_id`, then you may assign the `id` by hand not by `auto_increment` feature of MySQL.